# How to replace purchase order form id purchase.purchase_order_form to custom form id in odoo 10?

Tags: replace, odoo-10

I want to replace purchase order form id `purchase.purchase_order_form` to own `custom id` in **Odoo 10** using 
replace id priority or **X** path or other method using xml please sort out my problem and send some demo.

Comment: Just search a module have depending with Purchase, and you will find 1000 example to how inherit view

Comment: for exapme: go to the module `purchase_requisition/view/purchase_requisition_views.xml`, in the line 53 you will find an odoo example

Comment: Then copy/cut this example and change the necessary

Comment: What about views depending on that `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this:

```
<record id="purchase.purchase_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Purchase Order">
                <header>
                </header>
                </form>
            </field> 
</record>
```

don`t forget add depends for purchase at **manifest**.py

maybe this can help you